# Using `sqlalchemy` `insert` to bulk insert related objects

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to insert data into a table. The things I care about:

- I expect to be inserting a lot of data so want minimize the number of database execution.
- There will be duplicate entries, this is expected, so I'll use `on_conflict_do_nothing` (I'm using postgres).

As a minimal example, let's say I have two tables:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, String

Base = declarative_base()


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "addresses"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(String)
    number = Column(Integer)

class Person(Base)
    __tablename__ = "people"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("addresses.id")
    address = relationship("Address")
```

I can batch up all the `Address` inserts easily enough with:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
values = [{"street": "main", "number": 1}, {"street": "main", "number": 2}]
statement = insert(Address).values(values).on_conflict_do_nothing()
session.execute(statement)
```

The question is how do I then do the same with the `People`? I'm struggling with what to supply for `"address"`, e.g.

```py
values = [{"name": "John", "address": ????}]
statement = insert(Person).values(values).on_conflict_do_nothing()
session.execute(statement)
```

I'm assuming I need the `Address` object but then I don't know where to go from there?

Comment: Do you know the address id for each person? Have you tried just putting that into the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `address`, since it's not an SQL field. You can use [INSERT...RETURNING](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-update-returning) to get the IDs of the addresses you just inserted, and then set `values[0]['address_id']` based on that. Something like this should work:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
values = [{"street": "main", "number": 1}, {"street": "main", "number": 2}]
statement = insert(Address)\
    .values(values)\
    .returning(Address.id)\
    .on_conflict_do_nothing()
address_ids = [address_id for address_id, in session.execute(statement)]

values = [{"name": "John", "address_id": address_ids[0]}]
statement = insert(Person).values(values).on_conflict_do_nothing()
session.execute(statement)
```

**Explanation**

With `insert().on_conflict_do_nothing`, you're getting relatively close to the bare metal of PostgreSQL, compared to the added layers of SQLAlchemy. This is not a bad thing, it is of course where you have the most control and where the greatest speed ups happen, but it does mean that you need to think carefully about which fields are added by SQLAlchemy, and which fields are directly reflected by the database.

In your case, only `id`, `name`, and `address_id` are actual database columns. If you execute `SELECT * FROM people`, they are the only columns that should show up. In contrast, `address` is added by SQLAlchemy to give you a direct link to the `Address` instance with id `address_id`, but under water, a different call to the database is performed to fetch it, if necessary.

If you have an `Address` with id 1, then setting `john.address = 1` doesn't work, because 1 is not an address, it's a number. However, setting `john.address_id = 1`, does work, because you're setting a field directly. SQLAlchemy discourages this if you're using the full ORM (which you're not), because you do this outside of their ecosystem. If you run `john.address = Address.query.get(1)`, you assign the entire Address object to address, and SQLAlchemy updates `address_id` to 1 internally.